# Maximum call stack size exceeded?

Tags: reactjs, daterangepicker

i am adding date range picker in my project when i run daterange picker in a seperate project it works fine but when i try to integrate it with my project then i am getting this error with the same code "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
here is my code for date range picker
this is my Date.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import  {DateRangePicker}  from 'react-date-range';
import { addDays } from 'date-fns';

import moment from 'moment'
import 'react-date-range/dist/styles.css'; // main style file
import 'react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css'; // theme css file

class Date extends Component {
  handleSelect(ranges){
    console.log(ranges);
 
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectionRange: {
        startDate: new Date(),
        endDate: addDays(new Date(), 7),
       
        key: "selection"
      }
    }
  }
  

  handleDateSelect = (item) => {
    this.setState({
      ...item
    });
  }

  render()
  {
 
    return (
   
 
      <DateRangePicker
     
      onChange={(item) => this.setState({selectionRange: item.selection})}
   

      showSelectionPreview={true}
      moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
      months={2}
     
      ranges={[this.state.selectionRange]}
     
      direction="horizontal"
    />
    );
  }
}

export default Date
```

can anyone help me how to fix this ? i am getting this error in my console
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You class is named `Date` so when you call `new Date()` you are invoking the class's constructor.  This happens recursively and causes the stack overflow.

Try renaming your class to something else (like `DatePicker`).